# Migrating from jQuery to AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have some jQuery code that's a bit dated. I'm trying to migrate it to AngularJS. As part of that, I have a DIV that looks like the following:

```
<div id="infoMsg" class="infoMsg"></div>
```

Sometimes this DIV is hidden. Sometimes its visible. Its all based on user action. To toggle, I would use jQuery's built in show/hide methods like such:

```
$("#infoMsg", "#myPage").hide();
$("#infoMsg", "#myPage").show("blind");
```

The key piece here is the show("blind") component. The ["blind" effect](https://api.jqueryui.com/blind-effect/) gives the appearance of the element kind of sliding in. My question is, how can I do this same type of thing in the AngularJS world?

Currently, I have a flag on my scope defined as `$scope.showMessage = false`. My idea was to toggle that to make the div visible or not. However, that approach doesn't get me the nice "blind" effect.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599637/angularjs-ng-show-ng-hide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular provides a `$animation` service and `ngAnimate` directive in the `angular-animate.js` module (you have to include it separately, after `angular.js`). These things provide hooks that facilitate animations either through CSS transitions, CSS keyframe animations, or old school JS timeout loops/DOM modification ala jQuery.

You're encouraged to use CSS, as you get better performance and it is easier to separate and maintain presentation from markup and application code.

First, the [developer guide on animations](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations), second, an [angular animate tutorial](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/02/25/easy-animations-for-angularjs-with-animate-css.aspx), and lastly, [API docs for the `ngAnimate` module](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate).

When you include the `ngAnimate` module, certain directives will automatically hook into animate (such as `ngShow`, `ngHide`, `ngRepeat`, etc.). By default, they simply add classes to trigger CSS transitions and all you need to do is make sure you have CSS class names to do what you want.

In the case of `ngShow` (or `ngHide`), it will add the classes `ng-hide`, `ng-hide-add`, and then `ng-hide-add-active` to start transitioning when hiding. When the animation completes, it'll just leave `ng-hide`. When you show, it'll remove `ng-hide` and add `ng-hide-remove` and `ng-hide-remove-active`. Sounds complicated, but it's not bad. It's pretty formulaic. These states are there to facilitate smooth transitions.

For my example in [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/pe6SLXwAowjJZsXKPJG9?p=preview), all I did was include `angular-module.js` after `angular.js` and include `ngAnimate` in my module. Then I added the following CSS to make a crude blind-like animation for elements with the selector `.fancy`:

```
.fancy {
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background:red;
}

.fancy.ng-hide-add, .fancy.ng-hide-remove {
  -webkit-transition:all linear 5s;
  -moz-transition:all linear 5s;
  -o-transition:all linear 5s;
  transition:all linear 5s;
  display:block!important;
}

.fancy.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
.fancy.ng-hide-remove {
  max-height: 0;
}

.fancy.ng-hide-add,
.fancy.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
  max-height:100px;
}
```

This transition is just a simple example. You'll probably want improve on it, as the `max-height` thing is a bit of a hack. Consider using one created for you over at [Animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/).

Anyways, with the CSS is in place, all I do is use `ngShow` normally, giving the element the `fancy` class so the right transitions are applied when it shows and hides.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Its answers like this by people like you that make StackOverflow so great.