# How to hide certain elements in angular, based on the ng-class?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="version in allVersions" ng-class="{{ version['active'] == 'true' ? 'active' : 'inactive' }}">
 </tr>
```

I'm creating the `ng-class` based on the object and its working fine. I'm getting the expected output.

But what I want here is, `ng-class` whose value is `inactive` need to be hidden initially. On the click of a say button, it need to be shown. Basically like a toggle button, again if clicked, shows only `active` fields.

I tried this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="version in allVersions" ng-class="{{ version['active'] == 'true' ? 'active' : 'inactive' }}" ng-show="version['active'] == 'true'">
     </tr>
```

which is showing only `active`, but doesnt know how to proceed, if I want to show `inactive` on the button click.

`inactive` will be `inactive` always. On click of a button say `showall` it shows up, on button click `active` it hides, only `active` class are shown here.

New to angular, is there any easy to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599637/angularjs-ng-show-ng-hide

Comment: If you hide those elements wouldn't it be better to just filter and display the elements active or inactive?

Comment: @4EACH that's not what OP asked for

Comment: @maurycy: what you mean by `filer`?

Comment: `inactive` are hidden always or only before click? and after click they are still `inactive`?

Comment: `inactive` will be `inactive` always. On click on a button say 'all' it shows up, on button click `active` it hides.

Comment: No what I'm asking here is different. :( I know `ng-show`/`ng-hide`, but that doesnt work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this. In controller set this status property:

```
$scope.status = {
    active: true
};
```

And in HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="version in allVersions | filter:status" ng-class="[version.active ? 'active' : 'inactive']">
```

Then "Show All" and "Active" buttons could be configured this way:

```
<button ng-click="status = null">Show all</button>
<button ng-click="status = {active: true}">Active</button>
<button ng-click="status = {active: false}">Inactive</button>
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/BjiLYjPJG8yPBH1ysf7p?p=preview

Comment: Thanks thats brilliant. It works. Can you explain me whats exactly happening with filer? Because `filter:status` does return `true` for call cases right?

Comment: `status` is variable object. `filter` accepts it and filters array by properties in this `status` object. When `status={active: true}` it means that filter will only show elements where `active` property is `true`. When you set `status=null` it means no filtering at all.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`ng-show="version['active'] == 'true'"`

with

`ng-show="show(version['active'])"`

and add this to your controller. This assumes your showall() function sets a model variable `$scope.showAll` to true for "show all" and false for otherwise.

```
$scope.show = function(active) {
    return $scope.showAll || active;
}
```