# ng-show is not working in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

my json responce is {isVimeo = true } in angular js

```
<div ng-show={{isVimeo}}>
    ----
    ----
    ------
</div>
```

I want to show this div when isVimeo is true,but it is not display at my html.when i click inspect element in my html page the following code is there

```
<div ng-show="true" class="ng-hide">

</div>
```

when i remove the `ng-hide` class in inspect element it is displaying.By default it is not displayong

Can anyone help!

Thanks!

Comment: You do not need the `{{}}` brackets in ng-show. Just wrige `ng-show="isVimeo"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJs: ng-show / ng-hide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599637/angularjs-ng-show-ng-hide)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div ng-show="isVimeo">
```

And be sure $scope.isVimeo is set to true in the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('testApp',[]).controller('testCTRL',function($scope)
                               
{
  $scope.wantToShow = true;
  $scope.dontShow = false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<head>ng-show example:</head>
<body data-ng-app="testApp">
    <div data-ng-controller="testCTRL">
      
      <br>
      
      <b>ng-show is true:</b> 
      <span data-ng-show="wantToShow"> It is showing this becuase ng-show is true</span>
      
      <br><br>
      
      <b>ng-show is false(So,nothing we are showing):</b>
      
      <p data-ng-show="dontShow">It is showing this becuase ng-show is true</p>
      
    </div>
</body>
```