# AngularJS $scope variable does not go into view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple boolean variable that switches a DIV to be hidden at startup and then shown after an action until the end of the application. But it does not switch - the DIV is always hidden. Please help, what is wrong in the code below:

```html
<div class="right" ng-controller="EmployeeDetailsCtrl" ng-show={{showEmployeeDetails}}>
        <p>{{employee.name}} {{employee.surname}}</p>
</div>
```

inside EmployeeDetailsCtrl controller:

```
$scope.$on('showEmployee', function (event, data) {
    $scope.showEmployeeDetails = true;
    $scope.employee = data;
});
$scope.showEmployeeDetails = false;
```

BTW, the $scope.employee variable updates correctly after the event is triggered, so I'm really stuck what's going on here.

Comment: just move {{}} and make it ng-show="showEmployeeDetails" ...

Comment: It have more information about your question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12599637/2451726

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `{{}}` from your `ng-show`, like so:

```
<div class="right" ng-controller="EmployeeDetailsCtrl" ng-show="showEmployeeDetails">
        <p>{{employee.name}} {{employee.surname}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're using `ng-show` you're binding to an ***expression***, not a ***string***, so just use:

`ng-show="showEmployeeDetails"`. That's why you can do more complex stuff like `ng-show="1 + 1 === 2"`.

**If that still doesn't cut it**, it could be a scoping issue with primitives being assigned to a child scope and not seen up the parent scope. It doesn't look like it from the code you showed but perhaps it's simplified for this question, you never know.