# AngularJS ng-show confusion

Tags: angularjs

I have this in my template

```
<h1 ng-show={{campaignDataEmpty}}>You have no campaigns defined</h1>
{{campaignDataEmpty}}
```

When I breakpoint in the Chrome developer console, I can confirm that `$scope.campaignDataEmpty` is false.

The page displays

```
You have no campaigns defined
false
```

How can this be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJs: ng-show / ng-hide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599637/angularjs-ng-show-ng-hide)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the curley braces! `ngShow` already takes an Angular expression.

```
ng-show="campaignDataEmpty"
```