# How to display only href HTML code in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I use `{{message}}` in template HTML.
This code shows HTML as text in page.
How I can show only one HTML tag `<a href>` as HTML in page?

Comment: check ng-show / ng-hide or ng-if

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJs: ng-show / ng-hide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599637/angularjs-ng-show-ng-hide)

Comment: Not, You understood me wrong. I mean to show HTML text like as TEXT, except link

Comment: I think you need to explain the problem in more detail, probably with more code to illustrate what you want to accomplish.

Comment: You could use ng-sanitize

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense

Comment: @Mustafa can you provide an example of your desired output ? It is not clear what are you asking. What does message contains?

Comment: Have edited my question

Comment: Seems this is that I need: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/filter/linky

Comment: It helped me: http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

if have included ng-sanitize ([doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize)) as dependency you could its directive "ng-bind-html"  to sanitize your HTML-strings

```
<div ng-bind-html="message">
```