# Show and hide button using scope in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to hide button on specific action. For example when i show the Organization units record I want to hide locate button. Which is in the table grid.

Grid is showing the records of cities and organization units. I don't want a locate button to show when viewing organization units.

```
    $scope.showOrganizationunit=function(){

     show organization unit data 

      Hide button ( how to do it)
      can we use nghide here for the button



}
```

Comment: What have you tried ? There are plenty of solutions available for this question. Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599637/angularjs-ng-show-ng-hide

Answer (score 1):

You should add the HTML code, I will give you a generic sample:

HTML:

```
<button ng-show="organization" ng-click="showOrganizationunit()">Click me</button>
```

JS:

```
$scope.organization = true;
$scope.showOrganizationunit=function() {
   $scope.organization = false;
}
```

Another way much simpler is to define the scoped variable directly in the HTML, in this way you don't need any controller:

```
<button ng-show="organization" ng-click="organization = (organization) ? false : true">Click me</button>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/2x4s1mca/)