# AngularJS : ng-show usage

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to follow how ng-show and ng-hide work. I want a form to be shown when my REST call is a success and an error message if call returns me a null value.

I also went through [AngularJS: ng-show / ng-hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599637/angularjs-ng-show-ng-hide)

but still not following how they exactly work. Can anyone help?

Comment: code please? A plunker would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a promise

```
        var promise = service.Method();
         promise.then(function(response) {
            //Show
            $scope.elementVisibility = true; $scope.errorMsg = false;
         }, function(reason) {
            // Hide
            $scope.elementVisibility = false; $scope.errorMsg = true;
        });


    <form ng-show="elementVisibility"></form>
    <div ng-hide="errorMsg"></div>
```