# Why doesn't most simple case of Angular's ng-show work?

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

My unbelievably simple code:

```
AAAA
<div ng-show="false">
     XXXXX
</div>
BBBBBBB
```

Output:

```
AAAA
XXXXX
BBBBBBB
```

Why does `XXXXX` show up in the output? I told `ng-show` to hide it.

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v50oezss/1/

Comment: did you delete the last question and just copy paste it?

Comment: Your JSFiddle is not using Angular at all so there's no code doing anything with your DIV.  You have to reference the framework in order to use it.  https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/started

Comment: ...and use ng-app somewhere

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJs: ng-show / ng-hide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599637/angularjs-ng-show-ng-hide)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSFiddle is not using Angular at all so there's no code doing anything with your DIV. You have to reference the framework in order to use it.

Add a `<SCRIPT>` reference to angular.js and then do something like this:

```
<div ng-app> <!-- this initializes angular and hooks the framework -->
  AAAA
  <div ng-show="false">
       XXXXX
  </div>
  BBBBBBB
</div>
```

I [forked your JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ec9we1h/) so you can see it working.

Answer (score 2):

In your fiddle, you haven't used AngularJs; to do this you must add it as External Resources.
Furthermore you should used a ng-app like this:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-show="false">
     XXXXX
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

I make a fiddle for more clearness.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lpj5onvq/1/

Regards

Answer (score 2):

The other answers have correctly pointed out the problems.  The most important problem was that your jsfiddle wasn't referencing the AngularJS library so your `ng-show` wasn't doing anything because plain HTML will ignore it.

I updated the **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DrCool/v50oezss/9/)** so it now works.