# Update Item in List to be shown when tapped - Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a list that shows some items, here is the code that generates my list in my controller:

```
$scope.multipleOptions = [{ item: '1', checkmark:false}, { item: '2', checkmark:false},{ item: '3', checkmark:false} ];
```

Then in my HTML I have

```
<ion-list id="multiple-select-list" class=" ">
         <ion-item class="  " ng-repeat="multipleOption in multipleOptions track by $index" ng-click="checkSelected($index)">
                <p><b>{{multipleOption.item}}</b></p>
                <p class="button-icon ion-checkmark" ng-show="{{multipleOption.checkmark}}"></p>
        </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

As you can see when the list loads the checkmarks for all the items are hidden, and I have a function called `checkSelected($index)` that is called when an item is tapped, in that function I want to set the checkmark to be shown, here is what I currently have

```
$scope.checkSelected = function(modalIndex) {
        //this set the checkmark property to true
        $scope.multipleOptions[modalIndex].checkmark = true;
        //the line below does not work 
        document.getElementById("multipl-select-list").getElementsByTagName("ion-item")[modalIndex].getElementsByTagName("p")[1].show = true;
    }
```

In the above method I am able to set the checkmark variable of the item to ture but what I am having troubel with is making it show right when the item is tapped? How can I set the ng-show of the checkmark so it shows right when it is tapped?

**EDIT**
Solutions both worked I just wanted to add some behabiour I noticed, when I had `ng-show={{multipleOption.checkmark}}` the `ng-hide` class would be added to the class of that `<p>` so even when I set `ng-show` to true it would still not be shown

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML :

```
<ion-list id="multiple-select-list" class=" ">
         <ion-item class="  " ng-repeat="multipleOption in multipleOptions track by $index" ng-click="checkSelected(multipleOption)">
                <p><b>{{multipleOption.item}}</b></p>
                <p class="button-icon ion-checkmark" ng-show="multipleOption.checkmark"></p>
        </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

In javascript function :

```
$scope.checkSelected = function(data) {
    data.checkmark = true;
}
```

Comment: thanks would you mind taking a look at the edit I added, just wondering why that would happed

Comment: @iqueqiorio - sorry, but i didn't get you, can you re-phrase it

Comment: when I originally had `ng-show="{{multiple.checkmark}}"` they when I went to that page in my browser and looked at this tag `<p class="button-icon ion-checkmark" ng-show="multipleOption.checkmark"></p>` in the browser it showed `<p class="button-icon ion-checkmark ng-hide" ng-show="multipleOption.checkmark"></p>` It added `ng-hide` to the class, so even when I manually changed the `ng-show` attribute to `true` it still was not shown, until I deleted `ng-hide` from the class attribute, make sense?

Comment: What do you mean you changed manually the ng-show attribute ? By the time you have `ng-show="{{multiple.checkmark}}"` it gets it as `false` so angular automatically adds ng-hide class.

Comment: @iqueqiorio - make sense? hmmm, not completely, but i am assuming you changing manually in browser (developer console/firebug); changing ng-show to true or false won't hide or show the element, adding/removing ng-hide from class will hide/show the element

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your syntax. Try removing curly brackets. Also take a look a [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599637/angularjs-ng-show-ng-hide/#answer-12602481https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599637/angularjs-ng-show-ng-hide/#answer-12602481) answer

```
ng-show="multipleOption.checkmark"
```

Comment: thanks would you mind taking a look at the edit I added, just wondering why that would happed