# ng-view does not get the data from href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I tried one product page using AngularJS. This the first time i am creating the page using AngularJS.

`ng-view` is not working when i click the add to cart page. It does not show any respond.

I am verified the code with all the tutorials. It seems correct.

Can anyone please tell what i did wrong.

Below i mentioned the code. Sorry, cant able to put the code in jsfiddle. It does not bind the normal date.

Code:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);

   app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
     $routeProvider
       .when('/red', {
         templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
         controller: 'myCtrl',
       })
       .when('/green', {
         templateUrl: 'custom_directives.html',
         controller: 'myCtrl'
       })
       .when('/yellow', {
         templateUrl: 'custom_directives.html',
         controller: 'myCtrl'
       })
       .when('/black', {
         templateUrl: 'custom_directives.html',
         controller: 'myCtrl'
       })
       .when('/grey', {
         templateUrl: 'custom_directives.html',
         controller: 'myCtrl'
       })
       .when('/blue', {
         templateUrl: 'custom_directives.html',
         controller: 'myCtrl'
       });

     // configure html5 to get links working on jsfiddle
     $locationProvider.html5Mode({
       enabled: true,
       requireBase: false
     });
   });
   app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
     $scope.records = [{
       "Name": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
       "Country": "Germany",
       "Dollar": "$21.00",
       "URL": "red"
     }, {
       "Name": "Berglunds snabbköp",
       "Country": "Sweden",
       "Dollar": "$21.00",
       "URL": "green"
     }, {
       "Name": "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
       "Country": "Mexico",
       "Dollar": "$21.00",
       "URL": "yellow"
     }, {
       "Name": "Ernst Handel",
       "Country": "Austria",
       "Dollar": "$21.00",
       "URL": "black"

     }, {
       "Name": "Ernst Jubilie",
       "Country": "Canada",
       "Dollar": "$21.00",
       "URL": "grey"
     }, {
       "Name": "Idris_09090",
       "Country": "India",
       "Dollar": "$43.00",
       "URL": "blue"
     }]

   });
```

```css
li.list-group-item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  background-color: #D38585;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 25%;
  height: 210px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" style="background-color: #2a2326;" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="well well-sm" style="background-color:#2a2326; color:white; text-align:center; font-size:30px;">
      <h4><strong>Water Products</strong></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-12 col-lg-4" ng-repeat="x in records">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="group list-group-image" src="http://placehold.it/400x250/000/fff" alt="" />
        <div class="caption">
          <h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">
                            {{x.Name}}</h4>
          <p class="group inner list-group-item-text">
            {{x.Country}}</p>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
              <p class="lead">
                {{x.Dollar}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
               <a class="btn btn-success" ng-href="#{{x.URL}}">Add to cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </div>
```

Please help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
       enabled: true,
       requireBase: false
 });
```

change your url to 
`<a class="btn btn-success" ng-href="#/{{x.URL}}">Add to cart</a>`

demo:

https://plnkr.co/edit/5odGEUq0eK8tGR8IxohW?p=preview

Comment: Is it possible to hide the products , if i set the ng-click in Add to cart button.

Comment: yes you need to create a onclick event and toggle the hide/show with ng-show

Comment: I tried like this:  <a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="showAlert()" ng-href="#/{{x.URL}}">Add to cart</a> .... But it doesnot happen @madalin

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599637/angularjs-ng-show-ng-hide

Comment: you need to remove the ng-href and trigger the the page load after the showAlert()

Answer (score 1):

Change `href` to `ng-href`

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href ng-href="#{{x.URL}}">Add to cart</a>
```

Comment: but also add an empty `href` attribute (`<a href ng-href="#{{ x.URL }}">...</a>`)

Comment: I changed, still not responding @zarmony

Comment: @Idris : You need to put / after # : <a href ng-href="#/{{ x.URL }}">...</a>, please check my answer and let me know.

Comment: Nothing in console log @zarmony.

Comment: i tried, it redirects the url as .html#%2Fred @jigar

Comment: I'm just saying you should always add the empty `href` attribute, even if you use `ng-href`. It will work nonetheless if you omit it, but browsers render anchors without the href attribute differently, so if you want to follow standards - which you should - add it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this ? , as i can't judge is your app is getting load or not, but your href issue will solved from this.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);

   app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
     $routeProvider
       .when('/red', {
         templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
         controller: 'myCtrl',
       })
       .when('/green', {
         templateUrl: 'custom_directives.html',
         controller: 'myCtrl'
       })
       .when('/yellow', {
         templateUrl: 'custom_directives.html',
         controller: 'myCtrl'
       })
       .when('/black', {
         templateUrl: 'custom_directives.html',
         controller: 'myCtrl'
       })
       .when('/grey', {
         templateUrl: 'custom_directives.html',
         controller: 'myCtrl'
       })
       .when('/blue', {
         templateUrl: 'custom_directives.html',
         controller: 'myCtrl'
       });

     // configure html5 to get links working on jsfiddle
     $locationProvider.html5Mode({
       enabled: true,
       requireBase: false
     });
   });
   app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
     $scope.records = [{
       "Name": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
       "Country": "Germany",
       "Dollar": "$21.00",
       "URL": "red"
     }, {
       "Name": "Berglunds snabbköp",
       "Country": "Sweden",
       "Dollar": "$21.00",
       "URL": "green"
     }, {
       "Name": "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
       "Country": "Mexico",
       "Dollar": "$21.00",
       "URL": "yellow"
     }, {
       "Name": "Ernst Handel",
       "Country": "Austria",
       "Dollar": "$21.00",
       "URL": "black"

     }, {
       "Name": "Ernst Jubilie",
       "Country": "Canada",
       "Dollar": "$21.00",
       "URL": "grey"
     }, {
       "Name": "Idris_09090",
       "Country": "India",
       "Dollar": "$43.00",
       "URL": "blue"
     }]

   });
```

```css
li.list-group-item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  background-color: #D38585;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 25%;
  height: 210px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" style="background-color: #2a2326;" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="well well-sm" style="background-color:#2a2326; color:white; text-align:center; font-size:30px;">
      <h4><strong>Water Products</strong></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-12 col-lg-4" ng-repeat="x in records">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="group list-group-image" src="http://placehold.it/400x250/000/fff" alt="" />
        <div class="caption">
          <h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">
                            {{x.Name}}</h4>
          <p class="group inner list-group-item-text">
            {{x.Country}}</p>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
              <p class="lead">
                {{x.Dollar}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
              <a class="btn btn-success" ng-href="#/{{x.URL}}">Add to cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: /App_angular.html#%2Fred

Comment: can you see that, just hover cursor on you add card button, and analyse the link at right left bottom in browser? it is coming right one. Might be there should be a problem in your other code.

Comment: When i hover the button,

Comment: In this demo, just hover cursor in add to card button and see the link comin right

Comment: When, i hover the button in ADD TO CART, It shows "App_angular.html#/red"... But when i click the button it move the path to "file:///C:/Users/idris/Desktop/App_angular.html#%2Fred" in URL display

Comment: Yes coming @jigar

Comment: So now just make sure the given path should be right at :  templateUrl: 'custom_directives.html', is it correct?