# AngularJS : Field gets disabled with ng-disabled but can't hide with ng-hide

Tags: html, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and I've this doubt :

```
<select-one options="studentOptions" ng-disabled="student.type == 1"></select-one>
```

^
With the above code snippet, I'm able to disbale (or grey out) a bunch of radio buttons. but I want to hide those radio buttons so I changed it to this :

```
<select-one options="studentOptions" ng-hide="student.type == 1"></select-one>
```

However, it has no effect now! Can you help me understand where I'm going wrong? 
I expected those radio buttons to be hidden when I changed "ng-disabled" to "ng-hide", but I didn't get the expected results.

Comment: Please go through this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12602481/3366119

Comment: can you specify more about the directive you used  <select-one> like some link or code ?

Comment: If you are using your custom directive you can use **ng-if** should work instead of **ng-hide**.

Comment: @ImmanuelKirubaharanS using `ng-if` here will hide the whole select element  as you can see  he is using custom directive, so  i think  he may have to use a filter on studentOptions and opt out the value he need to hide

Comment: I want to hide ALL values

Comment: @JoelJoseph It seems he needs to hide the directive itself when ng-hide condition satisfy its criteria. So I think he still can use ng-if to achieve the same..